# WITH in tsql v Standard

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression, ansi-sql

Is `WITH` used in more places than just for `Common Table Expressions` in either `tsql` or `Standard SQL` functionality?

Reason I ask is that I'd like to know what the reason is that a semi-colon is enforced in the statement before a `CTE`s `WITH`.

I'm assuming that the semi-colon is to help the parser, especially if `WITH` is used in more than one context, or if they are planning on using it in more than one context.

Comment: ANSI SQL has no semi-colon before WITH.

Comment: Actually, ANSI SQL has semicolon as a statement terminator. Something which MS SQL Server never adopted (although it is allowed now, it's optional). The semicolon before `WITH` isn't there as some kind of prefix to the statement, but as the terminator for the previous statement because it's assumed that you probably didn't put one after your last statement.

Comment: `WITH` is used in many places (e.g. `WITH ENCRYPTION` or `WITH CHECK OPTION` or `RESTORE DATABASE ... WITH ...`). Very often this `WITH` is the last part of a statement. So - without the semi-colon - the parser cannot know whether this `WITH` is a new command or an appendix to the last one...

Comment: @jarlh tsql does not either!! it enforces a semicolon as a statement terminator of preceding statement

Comment: @TomH: actually the semicolon won't be "optional" in the future: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx "*Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version*"

Comment: Correct, it's a good idea to get into the habit of using it now.

Comment: ANSI SQL only specifies semicolon as terminator in PSM (stored procedures, triggers etc.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well I watched a walkthrough video with Itzik B-G a couple of days ago - it is on MicrVirtAcadamey - he is talking about the APPLY operator with Uday - one of the managers of SQL-Server. The way they talked about the semi-colon it sounded, to me at least, that this planned deprecation might never happen. I suspect if the lack of semi-colon really gets in the way of future functionality, or would mean that the parser/optimizer cannot cope, _then_ it will happen.

Comment: table hints  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx